# Google Apps Script to add links to google Spreadsheet adds 5000+ rows and i dont understand why?

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

Pretty self explanatory title, im trying to do a script where it takes the number on a column and uses that to search a list of files from google drive and then insert a link to that file.
HOWEVER, every time it inserts that link it also creates like 5000+ empty rows? why would this be?

The purpose is to take a number from a certain column, then look on google drive for the file that matches (at least partially) with that first number, then we should generate a link for that file and insert that link into another column, next to the number.

```
function CopiarResos() {
  let ass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let maxRows = ass.getSheetByName('set_de_datos_unificado').getMaxRows();
  let columnaResos = ass.getSheetByName('set_de_datos_unificado').getSheetValues(2,2,maxRows,1);
  let columnaLinks = ass.getSheetByName('set_de_datos_unificado').getSheetValues(2,53,maxRows,1);
  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1FJiet6tVgWXtM91Y7mmhgxDL2iYFm1VE'); // I change the folder ID  here 
  let list = [];
  let idList = [];
  let files = folder.getFiles();
  let match = '';
  while (files.hasNext()){
    file = files.next();
    list.push(file.getName().toString());
    idList.push(file.getId().toString());
  }
  console.log(list);
  console.log(idList);

/*
  let match = list.find(element => {
    if (element.includes(substring)) {
      return true;
    }
  });
*/

  for (let i = 0; i in columnaResos; i++){
    if(columnaLinks[i] == ""){
      let substring = columnaResos[i];
      match = list.find(element => {
        if (element.includes(substring)) {
          let idString = idList[i];
          let insertStr = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/" + idString +"view";
          let cellInsert = ass.getSheetByName('set_de_datos_unificado').getRange([i]+2,53);
          cellInsert.setValue(insertStr);
          return true;
        } 

      });

    }
  };



}
```

Comment: Hi, can you share a sample Sheets file that reproduces this behavior with the code above? Make sure this file doesn't contain sensitive information

Comment: Ive simplified it a bit (deleted most info other than whats relevant for my issue!) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-8-V8TEtyTNboBzDpinf_JjzCKb8rLEYNMo_K0ka3WQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You should clean up the linked spreadsheet and problable you should have to do the same on the original.... column BA has values on several cells from rows having no other other values.

Comment: I'm still unsure if this is intended or not, but I can see 2 issues. The first is related to "residual" data on empty lines which cause getLastRow() to return a value higher than the expected. The second issue, inside the for loop, you have `getRange([i]+2,53);` I believe the correct would be `getRange(i+2,53);`. I'm unsure about the intention, but just keep in mind that wherever value you've set, it'll be offset by 2 lines below. Can you share more details on what is the purpose of this loop and where do you expect the data to be set in the Sheet?

Comment: yes! ive solved the issue related to [i], that was causing the problem with the rows and stuff. lemme edit my post so i can add more info about the data

Answer (score 0):

`getMaxRows()` returns the number of rows that has the sheet (scroll down to the very bottom). You might delete the blank rows below your data or use `getLastRow()` instead.

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getmaxrows
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow

Comment: .....and i oop.

Comment: okay, i tried it with getLastRow(), however, it still does the same thing.

Comment: Have you tried the modified script on the spreadsheet linked in question comment?

Comment: yes, ive tried it and it still doesnt work :3

Answer (score 0):

So, apart from all the *thing wasnt written right* turns out i was missing a bunch of lines! Mostly i was trying to get a fileid from an array even tho the indexes were completely unrelated (eg: trying to get list[300] instead of doing indexOf(match)

```
function copiarResos() {
  let ass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let maxRows = ass.getSheetByName('set_de_datos_unificado').getLastRow();
  let columnaResos = ass.getSheetByName('set_de_datos_unificado').getSheetValues(2,2,maxRows,1);
  let columnaLinks = ass.getSheetByName('set_de_datos_unificado').getSheetValues(2,53,maxRows,1);
  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1FJiet6tVgWXtM91Y7mmhgxDL2iYFm1VE'); // I change the folder ID  here 
  let list = [];
  let files = folder.getFiles();
  let match = '';
  while (files.hasNext()){
    file = files.next();
    list.push(file.getName().toString(), file.getId().toString());

  }
  console.log(list);
  console.log(columnaLinks)
  
  for (let i = 0; i in columnaResos; i++){
 
    if(columnaLinks[i] == ''){
      let substring = columnaResos[i];
      match = list.find(element => {
        if (element.includes(substring)) {
          return true;
        } 
      });

      console.log(match);
      matchId = list.indexOf(match);
      
      if(matchId !== 0){
      console.log(match + " id es" + matchId);
      let idString = list[matchId+1];
      console.log(idString)
      let insertStr = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/" + idString +"/view?usp=sharing";
      let cellInsert = ass.getSheetByName('set_de_datos_unificado').getRange(i+2 ,53);
      cellInsert.setValue(insertStr);

      }

    }
    match = ''
  };



}
```